# How to set temporary for some script in fish?

Tags: fish

I have a directory which contains several projects, and I want to run some commands against each project.

Now what I'm doing is:

```
cd /my/project/root
set root (pwd)
for p in *
  cd $p
  git reset --hard HEAD
  git clean -dfx
  cd $root
end
```

It works but not quite elegant. Is there any better way to let the part:

```
 git reset --hard HEAD
 git clean -dfx
```

runs in a temporary working dir, so I don't need to record the `root` and `cd $root` in the end of each loop?

Answer (score 6):

Fish already maintains a history of recently visited directories so for your simple case just

```
for p in *
    cd $p
    do something
    cd -
end
```

There is also the pushd and popd commands for more complex use cases.

Comment: What about pushd and popd ?

Comment: Note that `cd ..` is slightly risky due to how fish handles symlinks. And I did mention pushd/popd :-)